# Manual Evolutions

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to execute evolutions manually, i.e. from the terminal, rather than on page reloads? If yes, how? I've searched the documentation, but found nothing on the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the sql file..

```
find . -name "*.sql" -print
```

The evolution will be called something like 1.sql

Edit the evolution script to make sure it is doing what you want. I found that I had to remove some drop table commands at the end. Finally import it thusly..

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p < 1.sql
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any convenience options, similar to rails `rake db:migrate`?